# In a certain city three car brands, A, B, C have... Is my solution correct?

Tags: probability

In a certain city three car brands, A, B, C have 20%, 30% and 50% of
the market share, respectively. The probability that the care needs major
repair during the first year of purchase for the three brands is 5%, 10%,
15%, respectively.

(a) What is the probability that a car in this city needs major repair
during its first year of purchase?

(b) What is the probability that a car requiring major repair during its
first year of purchase is from manufacturer A?

This is a (relatively) well known exercise problem from at least two books (Fundamentals of Communication Systems
By John G Proakis, Masoud Salehi AND Fundamentals of Applied Probability and Random Processes
By Oliver Ibe). My solution is as follows:

a. P(Repair) = P(A)*P(Repair|A) + P(B)*P(Repair|B) + P(C)*P(Repair|C) = 0.2*0.05 + 0.3*0.1 + 0.5*0.15 = 0.115

b. P(A|Repair) = P(Repair|A)*P(A)/P(Repair) = (0.2*0.05)/0.115 = 0.087

Is this correct? Can anyone please hint at the right solution if mine is wrong?

P.S: I searched on google for the solution to verify my answer but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Seems OK for me.

Comment: Perfect. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

You got it right. When I confront with those kind of problems (bayes law in particular) I visualize it for simplicity.

Here's my diagrams:

**A:**
[image]

**B:**
[image]